# gstat's krige.cv() error: "Error: dimensions do not match:"

Tags: r, kriging, gstat

I am using `krige.cv()` for cross validation of a data set with 1394 locations. In my code, empirical variogram estimation, model fitting, and kriging (by `krige()`) everything works fine. But when I use `krige.cv()` I get the following error.

> Error: dimensions do not match: locations 2786 and data 1394

One can notice that `1394 * 2 =  2786`. What could I be missing?
Please note that there are no `NA` or `NaN` or missing values in the data, variogram or kringing results. Everything works fine, and it's just `krige.cv()` that does not work.

Update: Here is the source code.

`library(gstat)`
`library(sp)`
`library(geoR)`

`data <- read.table("data.txt", header=T)`
`names(data)`
`attach(data)`

`#variable of interest`
`var = z`
`coordinates(data) = ~x + y`
`data.var <- variogram(var ~  1, data=data, cutoff=1, width=.05)`
`model <- fit.variogram(data.var, vgm(0.20, "Sph", nugget=0.06, range=1, fit.method=2))`
`poly <- chull(coordinates(data))`
`poly.in <- polygrid(seq(69.0, 74.1, 0.1), seq(31.5, 37.5, 0.1), coordinates(data)[poly,])`
`coordinates(poly.in) <- ~ x + y`
`krige.out <- krige(var ~ 1, data, poly.in, model=model)`
`krige.out.cv= krige.cv(var ~ 1, data, model=model)`

Comment: Can you provide a [minimal reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) which will help us to diagnose your problem?

Comment: Hi Phil, I have added an example code to my question. The data file has 3 columns (z, x, y) and 1394 rows. I have no idea how to attach it to my question.

Comment: You need to provide some data we can work with. See some of the answers to the question in the link I posted. I would expect you need to use `dput()`. Also your example should be *minimal*: strip your code down to the fewest lines needed to recreate your issue. There's a lot extra here.